# variadic form is ambiguous with the nonvariadic form for a single argument

Tags: c++, c++11

why in the following code compiler **doesn't**   complain because of ambiguity?

```
template <typename T>
void print (const T& arg)
{
std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}
template <typename T, typename... Types>
void print (const T& firstArg, const Types&... args)
{
std::cout << firstArg << std::endl;    // print first argument
print(args...);                       // call print() for remaining arguments
}
```

Comment: @VittorioRomeo He asked why doesn't complain, his code is compiled successful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because overload resolution always favours a non-variadic function form over a variadic one.

The C++11 standard insists on that.